# Why is the correlation function for position operator in the harmonic oscillator complex?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I'm dealing with the harmonic oscillator. I'm calculating the correlation function
$$c(t) = \langle 0 | x(t) x(0) |0 \rangle$$
where $|0\rangle$ is the ground state.

I'm dealing in the Heisenberg picture, where
$$x(t) = \exp(i H t / \hbar) x(0) \exp(-i H t / \hbar) \, .$$

Now, I have calculated the above using the ladder operator approach, and by explicit integration in the position representation, and I keep on getting the answer:

$$c(t) = \frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega} \exp(i\omega t)$$

How is it possible that my answer has a complex part? Surely the answer should be real since $x(t) x(0)$ is Hermitian. What is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that $x(0)x(t)$ is Hermitian? I would say that $[x(0), x(t)] \neq 0$ since $[x(0), H] \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two Hermitian matrices 
\begin{align}
A = A^{\dagger} \qquad B = B^{\dagger}
\end{align}
The product of two Hermitian matrices is not always Hermitian since $[A, B] \neq 0 $
\begin{align}
(AB)^{\dagger} = B^{\dagger} A^{\dagger} = BA \neq AB
\end{align}